# Process.Start in C# The system cannot find the file specified error using a variable name

Tags: c#, file, process

I am launching process in c# from parameters that are passed to the application.
The parameters are placed into variables which are then passed to the process start.

```
                    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                    startInfo.FileName = FileName;
                    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName);
                    startInfo.Arguments = Arguments;
                    startInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
                    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                    Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

I have tried using single slashes and double slashes in the paths but still get the same error.  This is a log file (ignore the dates and double equals) the paths are what the variable contained each test.  I tried double slashes and single slashes.

```
attempt 1
C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer
C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe

attempt 2
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
```

I also tried adding a "@" in front of the FileName variable hoping that might help (didn't)
Anyone have any ideas as to why this won't see the file?

Comment: What is that `@` in front of the FileName variable?

Comment: You don't need to add @ before FileName that is not a reserved keyword. What is the value of FileName ? Are you sure that the file designated by this value exists ? I don't understand `Wednesday, September 16, 2020 == C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer ...`.

Comment: Those are simply logs files I am writing out and I should have explained that above.   The dates are simply when the log was written.  After the double equals is what the variable contained at the time.

Answer (score -1):

These parameters were being passed through a protocol handler (HTML page) and spaces in the paths were replaced with   which was then removed and replaced with spaces in the application.  For some reason the replacement didn't exactly work even though the filename looked correct in the application the file was never seen.  I removed the   and replaced with the spaces in the HTML that calls the protocol handler (they were not needed) and now the files are seen correctly.   Not sure why they were like that to begin with unless the command line script in the registry did not have quotes around the %1 parameter